# Google App Engine - Directory missing on deploying nodejs app

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-app-engine, npm

I have a nodejs web app (based on koa.js) that is written in Typescript and I want to deploy it on Google App Engine.

The code is already transpiled to JavaScript and is located locally in `./dist/src/`.

So basically I want to deploy only `./package.json` and `./dist/src/`.

My app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs12
service: my-first-service
env_variables:
  somekey: somevalue
```

The start command in package.json: `node --require dotenv/config ./dist/src/App.js`

Uploading the app works fine. But it seems like the dist folder is missing. In the logs I can see `Error: Cannot find module '/srv/dist/src/App.js'`. Also in Stackdriver (debugging) I can't see the dist folder.

The dist folder is part of my `.gitignore` but not in `.gcloudignore`.

My .gcloudignore:

```
.env
.gitcommittemplate
.git
.gitignore
.gitlab-ci.yml
googleCloudKey.json
*.log
*.md
tsconfig.json
tslint.json

.nyc_output/
.vscode/
cli/
dist/tests/
node_modules/
src/
tests/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you included `src/` folder in `.gcloudignore`.

This is the reason why your /dist/src/ is missing [link](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

> For example, a pattern doc/frotz/ matches doc/frotz directory, but not
>   a/doc/frotz directory; however frotz/ matches frotz and a/frotz that
>   is a directory (all paths are relative from the .gitignore file).

I tested on my machine and got the same results. When I added `src` folder to my `.gcoudignore` file, both `src/` and `dist/src` were ignored.